# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails - deleting a post in blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've checked out the other answers to similar questions and I think I understand what they are a saying but I'm at a loss to how to solve it.

I get this error message, when trying to delete a post in the blog on my site. I've tried from Rails console and get a similar message also.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#destroy
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysite_development`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_2fd19c0db7` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 3
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [ :index, :show ]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }

    end

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Post</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your controller code. You added a [database foreign constraing](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) in your schema that disallows you to delete an object when there are associated records.

In this case, you are trying to delete an `Post` that has `Comments` attached. You need to alter the schema and update the foreign key definition to instruct the database what to do in this case. Specifically, you may probably want to delete the associated records on cascade.

In theory, you can use the `dependent: :destroy` Rails setting in the `Post` model to delete the `Comment`s on cascade, but it's not a good idea as you have a foreign key in place. It will be faster and better if you delegate the task to the database in this case.

Comment: Thanks Simone. I tried your recommended option but I couldn't make it work. I'm sure it's 100% valid I just wasn't able to figure it out due to lack of skill on that topic. Your second option worked for me, so I have a working app again. I will, however, try to figure out the recommendations with a little bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `dependent: :destroy` on the Model, which I imagine will be something like that. Luck.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score -2):

I only had enough time to do a quick skimming (so forgive me if I am overlooking things you may have already tried), though just noting to make sure that you clear/update fk's from all other tables linking to any values contained in the target table. There may be an automated way to do this rather than update every single table that uses a fk to that table, though in the meantime can be accomplish by simply clearing/updating those first, then executing the final update on the target table.